# Testing Views in django/Python

Tags: django-views, django-testing, django-tests

class UserProfile(APIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

```
def get(self, request):
    user = self.request.user
    user_id = user.id
    client_info = ClientInformation.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).values('full_name', 'address1', 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode')
    return JsonResponse(client_info[0])

def put(self, request):
    try:
        user = self.request.user
        user_id = user.id
        
        data = self.request.data
        full_name = data['full_name']
        address1 = data['address1']
        address2 = data['address2']
        city = data['city']
        state = data['state']
        zipcode = data['zipcode']
        ClientInformation.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).update(full_name=full_name, address1=address1, address2=address2, city=city, state=state, zipcode=zipcode)
        return Response({ 'success': 'Profile has been updated.' })
    except:
        return Response({ 'error': 'Something went wrong when updating profile.' })
```

class QuotesHistory(APIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

```
def get(self, request):
    user = self.request.user
    user_id = user.id
    quotes = list(FuelQuotes.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).values('id', 'gallons', 'delivery_address', 'delivery_date', 'price', 'amount_due'))
    return JsonResponse(quotes, safe=False)

def post(self, request):
    try:
        user = self.request.user
        user_id = user.id

        data = self.request.data
        FuelQuotes.objects.create(user_id=user_id, gallons=data['gallons'], delivery_address=data['delivery_address'], delivery_date=data['delivery_date'], price=data['price'], amount_due=data['amount_due'])
        print(FuelQuotes.objects.all())
        return Response({ 'success': 'Fuel quote has been submitted.' })
    except:
        return Response({ 'error': 'Something went wrong when submitting fuel quote.' })
```

class GetPrice(APIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

```
def get(self, request):
    user = self.request.user
    user_id = user.id
    gallons = int(self.request.data['gallons'])

    location_factor = 0.02 if ClientInformation.objects.get(user_id=user_id).state == 'TX' else 0.04
    history_factor = 0.01 if len(FuelQuotes.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)) != 0 else 0
    gallons_factor = 0.02 if gallons > 1000 else 0.03
    company_factor = 0.1
    price = (1.5 * (1 + (location_factor - history_factor + gallons_factor + company_factor)))
    return JsonResponse({"price": round(price,3), "amount_due": round(gallons * price, 2)})
```

I'm trying to build a testing page in django for this views page, but I'm encountering lots of challenges

Comment: Have you read the docs on the test client for requests? If not that might be a good place to start. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client

Comment: Doing it right now, thanks

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).